# Can I use the unique constraint in a schema with an extension?

Tags: xsd, schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.irs.gov/efile" 
elementFormDefault="qualified" 
attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
version="1.0">
    <xsd:element name="Form1120" type="Form1120Type">
        <xsd:unique name="uniqueCreditCode">
            <xsd:selector xpath="IncomeTaxCredits"/>
            <xsd:field xpath="CreditCode"/>
        </xsd:unique>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:complexType name="Form1120Type">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="CreditAvailable" type="CheckboxType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="IncomeTaxCredits" maxOccurs="10">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:complexContent>
                        <xsd:extension base="MSOtherIncFrancCreditsType">
                            <xsd:attribute name="referenceDocumentId" type="IdListType"/>
                        </xsd:extension>
                    </xsd:complexContent>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Examples

```
<IncomeTaxCredits>
 <CreditCode>10</CreditCode>
 <Amount>100</Amount>
<IncomeTaxCredits>

<IncomeTaxCredits>
 <CreditCode>10</CreditCode>
 <Amount>100</Amount>
<IncomeTaxCredits>
```

Lets say MSOtherIncFrancCreditsType contains two elements - CreditCode and Amount. CreditCode 10 can only be used once throughout the xml document. In the example it is used twice. Why is this valid based on the schema?

Comment: Your XML doesn't seem valid. Could you please verify that it's been copied and pasted and formatted properly?

Comment: I reposted the code.

Comment: @Rita: Check that I correctly interpreted my edits.

Comment: Yes (about the example)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a namespace with a prefix. change:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile" ...>
```

to:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:p="http://www.irs.gov/efile" ...>
```

then use this prefix in your xpath, like the following:

```
<xsd:element name="Form1120" type="Form1120Type">
    <xsd:unique name="uniqueCreditCode">
        <xsd:selector xpath="p:IncomeTaxCredits"/>
        <xsd:field xpath="p:CreditCode"/>
    </xsd:unique>
</xsd:element>
```

your complete xsd should look like the following:

```
 <xsd:schema xmlns:p="http://www.irs.gov/efile" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.irs.gov/efile" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
    version="1.0">
    <xsd:element name="Form1120" type="p:Form1120Type">
        <xsd:unique name="uniqueCreditCode">
            <xsd:selector xpath="p:IncomeTaxCredits"/>
            <xsd:field xpath="p:CreditCode"/>
        </xsd:unique>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:complexType name="Form1120Type">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="CreditAvailable" type="p:CheckboxType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="IncomeTaxCredits" maxOccurs="10">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:complexContent>
                        <xsd:extension base="p:MSOtherIncFrancCreditsType">
                            <xsd:attribute name="referenceDocumentId" type="p:IdListType"/>
                        </xsd:extension>
                    </xsd:complexContent>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Are you aware of an alternative solution?

Comment: I think you do not have another choice. you must use a namespace prefix. if you don't use XPath, you can use either a default namespace or namespace prefix.